# Dart Server Side: Where are the advantage of using Shelf rather than IO as a Web Server?

Tags: dart, server-side, dart-shelf

I want to use the RPC library to develop Dart server side Restful. In the library repository, it bring two exemples how to use (https://github.com/dart-lang/rpc-examples/tree/master/bin): Shelf and IO.

I would like to understand better the differences between Shelf and IO. Where are the advantage of using Shelf rather than IO as a Web Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shelf is a modular framework for a server application. Shelf is built on top of `dart:io`. There are [quite a few packages available for shelf](https://pub.dartlang.org/search?q=shelf)  (from the Dart team and 3rd-party) that make it quite easy to build complex server applications.
If you prefer to build your own solution use just `dart:io` directly.